# Getting Error as : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) while trying to get data using requests

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I have the below code:

```
count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"
headers= {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+token}

data = {"query":count_query}

url='https:....................'
try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    print(response.json) 
    print(response.status_code) 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Its giving the error as

```
Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

But when I replace the data value as

```
data = '{"query":"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"}'
```

Its working fine and I am getting the proper response. But the issue is , I cant hardcode one query. I have to use multiple queries which I have to  loop through an excel.

Could any one please help with this.

Comment: Maybe just do `data=str(data)` when your `data` is a dict.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send posts to https://httpbin.org/post and it will return a page describing the data that it received. In your first case it showed that the data sent was

```
"data": "query=SELECT+COUNT%28%2A%29+FROM+EMPLOYEE"
```

and in the second case it was

```
"data": "{\"query\":\"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE\"}"
```

The difference is that in the fist case `data` was form encoded and the second (after accounting for the extra escapes for the qoutes) was json.

Looking at the requests docs in [More complicated POST requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), its documented that if you pass a dict to `data` its form-encoded but if you pass a string its not. Your second one works because that string is valid json.

Since you are passing "application/json", you should just pass a json encoded string. `requests` has a parameter that will do the encoding for you, just switch from using `data=` to `json=`

```
count_query="SELECT COUNT(*) FROM EMPLOYEE"
headers= {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer'+' '+token}

data = {"query":count_query}

url='https:....................'
try:
    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=data)
    print(response.json) 
    print(response.status_code) 

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```